# "java.lang.String cannot be cast to ..." usando controle de acesso no Servlet

Tags: java, servlet, filter

Tenho um sistema feito pra minha empresa e junto tenho o website novo.
Consigo logar no sistema normalmente com as contas registradas no banco de dados, porém quando insiro um filter no servlet, recebo a mensagem:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to UTIL.Usuario

Se eliminar o filtro, o sistema funciona normalmente. O filtro que estou usando é para impedir que as páginas do sistema sejam acessadas via url, sendo assim redirecionado sempre para o `login.jsp`.

Segue o código.

`FiltroSeguranca.java`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class FiltroSeguranca implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) req).getSession();

        Usuario usuario = (Usuario) session.getAttribute("name");

        if (usuario == null) {

            session.setAttribute("msg", "Você não está logado no sistema!");

            ((HttpServletResponse) res).sendRedirect("login.jsp");

        } else {

            chain.doFilter(req, res);

        }

    }

    public void destroy() {

    }

}
```

**web.xml**:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>UTIL.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>
<filter>
    <filter-name>Filtro Seguranca</filter-name>
    <filter-class>UTIL.FiltroSeguranca</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filtro Seguranca</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/GrantedAccess.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/Cadastro.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**ATUALIZADO**

**Login Servlet**

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String n = request.getParameter("username");
        String p = request.getParameter("userpass");

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.setAttribute("name", n);
        }

        if (LoginDao.validate(n, p)) {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("GrantedAccess.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } else {
            out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry username or password error</p>");
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
        }

        out.close();
    }

}
```

**LOGIN FORM**

```html
<div id="conteudo" class="animated fadeIn">
    <div id="raside">
        <div class="animated flash">
            <h1>

                <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
                    LOGIN  <input autofocus type="text" name="username" required>
                    SENHA  <input type="password" name="userpass" required>
                    <input type="submit" value="AUTENTICAR">
                </form>

            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como você está setando o atributo `name` na sessão? Provavelmente o valor não é uma instância de `Usuario`, e sim uma string.

Comment: Tá vindo como String a partir do LoginServlet

Comment: Consegue incluir o trecho do `LoginServlet` que disse?

Comment: acabei de inserir

Comment: Realmente, você está setando como *string* e tentando recuperar como `Usuario`, já incluo uma resposta para você

Comment: Obrigado!!!! o/

Answer (score 2):

Conforme falado nos comentários, você está adicionando à sessão um atributo chamado `name` com o tipo `String` e depois tentando recuperá-lo e fazendo *cast* para o tipo `Usuario`.

Uma [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) é lançada sempre que você tenta converter um objeto a outro tipo de qual ele não é uma instância.

Veja este trecho de `LoginServlet`:

```
// recupera como String
String n = request.getParameter("username");
String p = request.getParameter("userpass");

HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
    // configura "name" na sessão como String
    session.setAttribute("name", n);
}
```

Como nos comentários, você está trabalhando sempre com o tipo `String`. Agora perceba como está fazendo em `FiltroSeguranca`:

```
Usuario usuario = (Usuario) session.getAttribute("name");
```

Opz, temos um problema. Antes falamos que `name` era uma instância de `String` e agora estamos convertendo para um tipo não equivalente. Não sei como está o restante de sua aplicação, mas uma forma simples de corrigir é alterar o trecho acima por este:

```
String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("name");

// assumindo que tenha um construtor que receba uma string =D
Usuario usuario = new Usuario(userName);

// continua seu código ....
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!!! vou testar aqui e posto o resultado!!